# LINQ query returns wrong results when used on in-memory data

Tags: sql, linq

I have a query (in SQL) that i run in SSMS and get a result set with 32 rows, just like I want.

I then convert my SQL query to a LINQ query, line by line, and run it in Visual Studio against the same database and get a list of 32 rows - just like I want.

Here comes the problem.
If I do something like this

```
MyEntities entities = new MyEntities();
List<MyEntity> resultset = entities.MyEntity.ToList();
```

...and run my LINQ query against the in-memory data collection I only get 27 rows and now some of the rows are repeated so they are not even distinct - but they certainly are in the database.

I presume this is because LINQ generates SQL when sending queries to a database (and so the result is correct) but do something else when the target is an in-memory data structure. Not sure what is going on here. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Just to clarify. This gives the correct result

```
List<MyEntity> results = entities.MyEntity.Where(x => x == ...).ToList();
```

This does NOT

```
MyEntities entities = new MyEntities();
List<MyEntity> listData = entities.MyEntity.ToList();

List<MyEntity> results = listData.Where(x => x == ...).ToList();
```

Comment: What is the generated SQL query? Check in SQL Server Profiler.

Comment: One common reason for differences like this is that Sql is (usually) case insensitive where linq to objects is case sensitive.

Comment: I dont have permissions to run traces on the server, unfortunately. 

Perhaps I was not clear enough ..when I said that the correct result was returned when the query was run directly against the database, this was what I meant..

List<MyEntity> result = entities.MyEntity.Where(x => x = ..).ToList();

Answer (score 1):

Resolved it!

The solution was to set a primary key in the database table.

Thanks anyway :)